# How do i add a photo to a template using the admin panel?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

consider this my `models.py` file.

```
from django.db import models

class alldets(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default ='first name')
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='second name')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='school name')
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='where from')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='phone number')
    age = models.IntegerField(default='254')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

How do i add a photo just to it then parse it to the views.py and then to the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all install Pillow

```
pip install pillow
```

Then `models.py`

```
class AllDets(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default ='first name')
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='second name')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='school name')
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='where from')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='phone number')
    age = models.IntegerField(default='254')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/photos')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

If you want to make the model available in django admin, register the model in `admin.py`

```
from .models import AllDets

admin.site.register(AllDets)
```

You can retrieve data in `views.py` as usual

```
from .models import AllDets
    
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'all_dets' : AllDets.objects.all(),
        }
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

Then in `index.html` you can render data as follows

```
{{all_dets.first_name}}
{{all_dets.second_name}}
{{all_dets.school}}
{{all_dets.county}}
{{all_dets.phone}}
{{all_dets.age}}
{{all_dets.photo.url}}
```

and remember to add enctype on your form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But it is not working. Is there something i have to do to the settings.py file?

Comment: Include Traceback